# Office.js displayDialogAsync error when displayInIframe: false

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to display, in an outlook web add-in, a dialog from a taskpane using the `displayDialogAsync` function. At first, I used `displayInIframe: true` and everything was working wonderfully, but for some reason I needed it to display in its own page.

So I changed the options to `displayInIframe: false`, and that causes a prompt to open. When it opens and I click **Allow**, I get a `JSON.parser` error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at O (outlook-web-16.01.js:20:204476) at HTMLInputElement.Y.f.onclick (outlook-web-16.01.js:20:196995)`

It's comming from this line: `var windowName = JSON.parse(window.name);`

I tried turning the prompt off using `promptBeforeOpen: false`, but as it says in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices), "When this option is set to false, Office on the web will not prompt the user to allow the add-in open a dialog, and the Office dialog will not open."

I was wondering if I was missing something, or if you can't actually open a dialog outside of an iframe in a taskpane?

Here is my code:

```
const dialogUrl = "https://office365.localhost.com/test.html";
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
                       dialogUrl, 
                       { 
                            displayInIframe: false,
                            height: 80,
                            width: 80
                        }, 
                       (result) => {
                            //Code
                        
                       }
                });
```

***Update***
Display dialog with `displayInIframe: false` now works with the last microsoft update

Comment: This looks like a bug. If you don't get an answer here in a couple of days, consider creating an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Alright, will do.

Comment: What happens when you set `window.name = '""';` before calling `displayDialogAsync()`?

Comment: @Tomalak I just tried it and I get a different error now : "Cannot read properties of null (reading '_appName')"

Comment: Well, it was an idea. I also think this is a bug. If you don't get a reply here, and can't upgrade the office.js version either, then *maybe* it's possibe to work around the bug by following the exceptions in the brower's debugger, and "monkey-patching" variable values until it's no longer giving you errors. Worth a try. Next step I would attempt: Look at the `window.name` when you have `displayInIframe: true` and use that kind of structure instead of `window.name = '""';`.

Comment: I've looked into this and the window.name is the same when you use displayInIframe: true or false. The call stack is juste not the same. I've reported the issue to the officejs developpers. Thank you @Tomalak

Comment: May I know which version of office fixed it because I am trying the same with displayInIframe: false and it does not open up a pop up at all